# How update inner value of a jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

For example I need to update `bok.name` (from `life book` to `new name`) for entry containing `classifiedId` = `665`. How I can do it?

This is an example of my `jsonb` column with name `external_ids`:

```json
{
  "book": {
    "id": "1223",
    "name": "life book"
  },
  "keyId": "662123",
  "classifiedId": "665"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update inside a jsonb-column using `jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing boolean])`.

```sql
UPDATE test 
SET external_ids = jsonb_set(external_ids, '{book,name}', '"new name"', false) 
WHERE external_ids::jsonb->>'classifiedId'='665';
```

The path supplied as the second argument indicates the keys in the set to find the point of update, and the third argument is the value to insert at the given path, in jsonb-format.